# This an event study difference in differences regression equation. how can we transform this stata code to R code?

Tags: r, stata

reg laccidentsvso2 weakban strongban lpop lunemp permale2  lrgastax laccidentmv2 st1-st50 t1-t48 time stt1-stt50 [aweight=pop],cluster(state)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent of the Stata `regress` command in R, but the following code should produce the same results:

```
library(lmtest)

model1 <- lm(laccidentsvso2 ~ weakban + strongban + lpop + lunemp + permale2 + lrgastax + laccidentmv2 + st1-st50 + t1-t48 + time + stt1-stt50, data = rstata, weights = aweight)

model2 <- lm(laccidentsvso2 ~ weakban + strongban + lpop + lunemp + permale2 + lrgastax + laccidentmv2 + st1-st50 + t1-t48 + time + stt1-stt50 + cluster(state), data = rstata, weights = aweight)

coeftest(model1, model2)
```